# Word counting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out a way to count words that are placed in multiple paragraph blocks in javascript. Right now I have a button that is connected to a function and that function is linked to an ID in the paragraph. Here is my code

```js
function processText(elements) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    count += elements[i].textContent.split(/\s/).length;
  }
  return count;
}
var wordsInParagraphs = processText(document.getElementsByTagName("data"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="title" content="The Cask of Amontillado--Edgar Allan Poe (1809-1849)">
</head>

<body>
  <p><button 1="processText(elements);">Process</button></p>
  <p id="data"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: what is `1="processText(elements);"`?

Comment: just something i'm using to make this function different. Probably not necessary though.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("data")`? and the markup has tags with `id="data"`?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're actually trying to do here. To start with, you aren't doing anything with `var wordsInParagraphs`, you have no `data` tags, and you have no actual text to parse.

Comment: Isn't that the fastest way to identify what content is in my paragraphs? Excuse me if i'm wrong by the way. I am a relatively new programming student

Comment: I have the text but its about 400 lines of a short story. Should I include that? Also what do you mean by I have no data tags? Isn't that what I included in the first <p> tag? If not where should I include them?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("data")` What you think it does?

Comment: Shouldn't that read everything that's assigned to the id "data" and then finish whatever process document.getElementsByTagName is connected to? Again, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You just need to call the function on click and grab all the elements you want to count, you have the rest there (I'm using split instead of regex).

```js
function processText() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".data");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    count += elements[i].textContent.split(" ").length;
  }
  console.log(count)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="title" content="The Cask of Amontillado--Edgar Allan Poe (1809-1849)">
</head>

<body>
  <p><button onclick="processText();">Process</button></p>
  <p class="data">text in paragraph one</p>
  <p class="data">text in paragraph two</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The markup has some problems, for example, `1="processText(elements);"` probably you meant `onClick="processText(elements);"`, however, you're passing a param called `elements`.  Further, you have a tag with `id="data"` and you're trying to look for tag name those elements.

A better approach is using the function `addEventListener` for a better logic and you should mark those paragraphs using a class name `class="data"`. Finally, for splitting by spaces use this regex `/\s+/`

```js
function processText(elements) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    count += elements[i].textContent.split(/\s+/).length;
  }
  return count;
}

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var wordsInParagraphs = processText(document.getElementsByClassName("data"));
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = wordsInParagraphs;
});
```

```html
<p><button id='myButton'>Process</button></p>
<p class="data">Ele from Stack</p>
<p class="data">Ele from &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Venezuela</p>
<p id='total'></p>
```